# sqlite: SQLiteDase.query not working as expected

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table like so:

```
1|EC7599A156DB1913AD9DE9A3A9540624B05683EC|Bar|World's Greatest|http://www.foo.com
2|EC7599A156DB1913AD9DE9A3A9540624B05683EC|Bar|World's Greatest|http://www.foo.com
3|EC7599A156DB1913AD9DE9A3A9540624B05683EC|Bar|World's Greatest|http://www.foo.com
```

The schema for the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IRChannels (
    ChannelId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    ChannelHash BLOB NOT NULL, 
    ChannelTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
    ChannelDesc TEXT, 
    ChannelLink TEXT);
```

I try to run a `SELECT` statement using the following code:

```
if (mReadDatabase != null) {
     String[]   columns = new String[]{COL_CHANNEL_ID};
     String     selection = COL_CHANNEL_HASH + "='" + hash + "'";
     try {
         Cursor cursor = mReadDatabase.query(
             TABLE_CHANNELS_NAME,      // Table Name 
             columns,                  // Channel ID
             selection,                // WHERE ChannelHash
             null,                     // = hash
             null,                     // Don't  Group
             null,                     // Don't filter by Groups
             null,                     // Use default Sort Order
             String.valueOf(1));       // LIMIT 1

         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             return cursor;
         } else 
             return null;
    }
```

Problem is I never see any data in the returned cursor. If I try the following command in the sqlite3 shell, I'm able to get the data:

```
select channelid 
from irchannels 
where channelhash='EC7599A156DB1913AD9DE9A3A9540624B05683EC' 
limit 1
```

What could I be missing?

**UPDATE:**
I tried changing my code to using raw query like so, still no difference:

```
if (mReadDatabase != null) {
    String        selection = COL_CHANNEL_HASH + "='" + hash + "'";
    final String  rawQuery = "SELECT " + COL_CHANNEL_ID +  
                " FROM " + TABLE_CHANNELS_NAME + " " + 
                " WHERE " + selection + 
                " LIMIT 1;";
        Cursor cursor = mReadDatabase.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
}
```

Comment: Just check whether you get value for Cursor using cursor.getCount();

Comment: if (mNotesCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
          contactname = mNotesCursor.getString(nameColumn);
         } while (mNotesCursor.moveToNext());
     }

Comment: `cursor.moveToFirst()` is returning false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
String[]   columns = new String[]{COL_CHANNEL_ID};

Cursor cursor = mReadDatabase.query(
             TABLE_CHANNELS_NAME,      // Table Name 
             columns,                  // Channel ID
             "column_name=?",                // WHERE ChannelHash
             new String[]{hash},                     // = hash
             null,                     // Don't  Group
             null,                     // Don't filter by Groups
             null,                     // Use default Sort Order
             String.valueOf(1));       // LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Tried it already. Same results. The documentation of `rawquery` @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]) says 
"You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings"

Comment: changed code to: `mReadDatabase.rawQuery(rawQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(1)});` for testing. Same results.

Comment: Try my updated answer and give the column_name as you have given in creating the table.

Comment: Hmm... weird, it did not work initially, so I tried @Yury's given suggestion. Then it worked. After that I changed my column name back to `ChannelId` and it started working just fine. I really don't understand what's going on. I have another weird problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656146/column-not-created-in-sqlite3-table). Maybe just having a bad day. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I've read that android requires for id field special name. You can get it as in the example:

```
public static final String COL_CHANNEL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
```

And the schema should be the following in your case:

```
CREATE TABLE IRChannels (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    ChannelHash BLOB NOT NULL, 
    ChannelTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
    ChannelDesc TEXT, 
    ChannelLink TEXT);
```

Because BaseColumns._ID usually equal to "_id"

Comment: Weird, it does seem to fix the problem initially, but now I have replaced the column name back to `ChannelId` and it seems to be working. The only thing that happened in between was I tried @Lalit Poptani recommendation.