# Column not created in SQLITE3 table

Tags: android, sqlite

Now I have a weird problem, I've done all kinds of test and I believe I'm seeing something weird.

I create three tables in SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CHANNELS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_FEEDS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_FEEDMAP_CREATE);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The CREATE statements for the three tables follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IRChannels (
    ChannelId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    ChannelHash TEXT NOT NULL, 
    ChannelTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
    ChannelDesc TEXT, ChannelLink TEXT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IRFeeds (
    FeedId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    FeedHash TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedDescription TEXT, 
    FeedLink TEXT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IRFeedMap (
    ChannelHash_FK TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedHash_FK TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ChannelHash_FK) REFERENCES IRChannels (ChannelHash), 
    FOREIGN KEY (FeedHash_FK) REFERENCES IRFeeds (FeedHash));
```

The problem is apparently the column `FeedHash` in `IRFeeds` is not created while others are. I'm looking at the output in sqlite3 command prompt;

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE IRChannels (
    ChannelId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    ChannelHash TEXT NOT NULL, 
    ChannelTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
    ChannelDesc TEXT,         
    ChannelLink TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IRFeedMap (
    ChannelHash_FK TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedHash_FK TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ChannelHash_FK) REFERENCES IRChannels (ChannelHash), 
    FOREIGN KEY (FeedHash_FK) REFERENCES IRFeeds (FeedHash));
CREATE TABLE IRFeeds (
    FeedId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    FeedHash TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedTitle TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedDescription TEXT, 
    FeedLink TEXT);
```

This does list the `FeedHash` column in `IRFeeds`. However, when I execute

```
sqlite> select * from IRFeeds where FeedHash='';
SQL error: no such column: FeedHash
```

All other columns do not give such errors. This condition is causing my code to fail unexpectedly as well. What could I be missing?

```
sqlite> select * from IRFeeds where FeedID=1;
sqlite> select * from IRFeeds where FeedTitle='';
sqlite> select * from IRFeeds where FeedDescription='';
sqlite> select * from IRFeeds where FeedLink='';
```

No errors above when I execute `select` statement for other columns.

Comment: Interestingly, `QUESTOID SQLLite Manager` (http://jaxenter.com/manage-sqlite-for-android-11339.html) gives the following error when i try to open my database: `Could not create the view: [line 1:58] no viable alternative at character ' '
CREATE TABLE IRFeeds (FeedId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FeedHash TEXT NOT NULL, FeedTitle TEXT NOT NULL, FeedDescription TEXT, FeedLink TEXT)`

Comment: Found this thread (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1732). Not sure if what i see is related, but still helps.

Comment: Sigh! Very odd indeed. If I manually `drop irfeeds` and `create table irfeeds (...)` then execute my code, everything works as expected. Wondering if this has something to do with the fact that I'm creating multiple tables in SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate.

Comment: Found a newer thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663717/creates-db-with-wrong-number-columns which seems to be having similar problems. Still no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an entire day of struggle, I managed to isolate why the problem triggers. Still don't know why, but it does fix the problem. The problems occurs because of the following table which has foreign keys on the other two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IRFeedMap (
    ChannelHash_FK TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedHash_FK TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ChannelHash_FK) REFERENCES IRChannels (ChannelHash), 
    FOREIGN KEY (FeedHash_FK) REFERENCES IRFeeds (FeedHash));
```

Changing the column names of foreign key columns to be the same as the column they reference fixes the problem. I changed the statement above to:

```
CREATE TABLE IRFeedMap (
    ChannelHash TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FeedHash TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ChannelHash) REFERENCES IRChannels (ChannelHash), 
    FOREIGN KEY (FeedHash) REFERENCES IRFeeds (FeedHash));
```

And voila! Sanity was restored. Beats me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your SQL. I tested and everything was created properly. Also your SQL query did not cause `no such column` error. So try to delete the database with `context.deleteDatabase(databaseName);` and try again.

Comment: I have deleted the database several times over using DDMS. Let me now do a full reboot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nope. Rebooting and "Wiping User Data" did not help. I'm running in the emulator. Wonder what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a SQLite reserved word (column, that was)

I ended up in this SO question, so maybe it helps others in my situation