# Creates db with wrong number columns

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to create a table with 4 columns (including _id) and no matter what I do it keeps on creating a table with only 3 columns (including _id).

My table definition is the following:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table collections (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, description text not null, image integer not null);";
```

And my onCreate:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
```

How I'm accessing the data:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext); 
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);


        i.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(3));  //access to the image column
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));

        // The preferred Gallery item background
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);


        ll.addView(i); 

        TextView tv = new TextView(ll.getContext());

        tv.setTag(mText[position]);
        tv.setText(cursor.getString(1)); //access to the name column
        tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(48, 48));
        ll.addView(tv); 

        return ll;
    }
```

No matter what I try, it keeps leaving the column image out of the table… I'll appreciate any help I get.

Comment: Have you tried naming the column `_image`?

Comment: Well I'm been having the same problem myself, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656146/column-not-created-in-sqlite3-table. Please let me know if you find out why. I've reworked my code and column names umpteen times, nothing seems to work. It's like a ghost column.

Comment: Change image column name to something else and try.

Comment: @joe_coolish Yes I've tried that. No luck.

Comment: which column will be left out?

Comment: @thinksteep No luck there too.

Comment: @WarrenFaith - image. And no matter the number of columns I add to it keeps creating a 3 column table.

Comment: Maybe try another order?

Comment: do you have more tables/data in same database? could that be space issue? just exploring possible issues.

Comment: Have you removed and installed the app again? Are you sure your app does not have a "old version" created?

Comment: another approach you may try is, ALTER table.

Comment: I'm always cleaning any previous data (manually on the smartphone) so  it's not possible that there are any other previous versions.

No space issue here, I have more than 20 MB free.

Comment: @thinksteep I tried to add the column through ALTER but got a error saying that there was already a column with that name.

Comment: that means physically column exists in DB. How are you validating that perticular column is not created? As final try can you do insert and see it is working or not?

Comment: @thinksteep I can do inserts but when I try to access the data in that column it says that is out of bounds and that the table has 3 columns. I also made sure through getColumnsCount() and it also shows 3.

Comment: Then I feel something wrong with sqllite on your phone.

Comment: Could you please provide the code on how you access the data? and please ad the error message, too. I guess you just mess up on database select...

Comment: Try .schema in sqlite3 command prompt does it show the ghost column? In my case it does. I manually drop the table and create it from the command line. Then everything works as expected. This is not an acceptable solution however.

Comment: My problem has been isolated and fix. See if the solution helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656146/column-not-created-in-sqlite3-table/8665184#8665184. Essentially, in my case, I was having foreign key columns which has names which were different from the column they referenced. Changing the column names to be the same fixed the problem. I am so relieved!

Answer (score 1):

It was a really dumb thing and I'm really sorry for wasting anyone's time. I really appreciate everyone's help.

I wasn't fetching the data correctly. So in the future if anyone repeats my mistake check your fetch methods first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including backticks around your table and column names?  This will do some escaping for you:

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table `collections` (`_id` integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "`name` text not null, `description` text not null, `image` integer not null);";
```

Comment: Tried this solution and it didn't work, got a warning message that the table didn't exist instead.

Answer (score 0):

**wild unproved guess:** As `_id` might be ignored or recognized as the default `_ID` column, its possible that it will not be counted.

Try to get the column number dynamically:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext); 
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);


    i.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("image")));  //access to the image column
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));

    // The preferred Gallery item background
    i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);


    ll.addView(i); 

    TextView tv = new TextView(ll.getContext());

    tv.setTag(mText[position]);
    tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))); //access to the name column
    tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(48, 48));
    ll.addView(tv); 

    return ll;
}
```

To the rest (off topic):

1. You should read about recycling views in an adapter
2. You could also try the SimpleCursorAdapter class

Comment: Didn't work. I can't use SimpleCursorAdapter in this case because I'm using a Gallery to show the data.